# How can I convert the URL into NDN format?

Tags: regex, url

i want to convert the format of URL to NDN format like this example:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

/com/stackoverflow/questions/ask
```

Using c++ or python, how can I achieve this with regular expressions (regex)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1

Maybe,

```
(?i)^(?:https?:\/\/)(?:w{3}\.)?([^\r\n]+?)\.([a-z0-9]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z0-9]{2,6})?)\/?(.*)$
```

and a replacement of,

```
/\2/\1/\3
```

might be OK to look into.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i9iu5H/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
https://stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/ask
https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
http://www.stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/ask
http://www.stackoverflow.co.uk/
http://www.stackoverflow.co.uk
'''

expression = r'(?im)^(?:https?:\/\/)(?:w{3}\.)?([^\r\n]+?)\.([a-z0-9]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z0-9]{2,6})?)\/?(.*)$'

print(re.sub(expression, r'/\2/\1/\3', string))
```

#### Output

```
/com/stackoverflow/questions/ask
/co.uk/stackoverflow/questions/ask
/com/stackoverflow/questions/ask
/co.uk/stackoverflow/questions/ask
/co.uk/stackoverflow/
/co.uk/stackoverflow/
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PBMXTH/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/PBMXTH/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

### Method 2

Here, we'd create an optional capturing group 2, for if there would `.co.uk` instances:

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/B0hFdf/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
https://stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/ask
https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
http://www.stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/ask
http://www.stackoverflow.co.uk/
http://www.stackoverflow.co.uk
'''

expression = r'(?im)^(?:https?:\/\/)(?:w{3}\.)?([^\r\n]+?)\.([a-z0-9]{2,6})\.?([a-z0-9]{2,6})?\/?(.*)$'

output = []
for match in re.findall(expression, string):
    if match[2] != '':
        NDN = '/' + match[2] + '/' + match[1] + '/' + match[0] + '/' + match[3]
    else:
        NDN = '/' + match[1] + '/' + match[0] + '/' + match[3]

    if NDN[-1] != '/':
        NDN = NDN + '/'

    output.append(NDN)

print(output)
```

#### Output

> ['/com/stackoverflow/questions/ask/',
>   '/uk/co/stackoverflow/questions/ask/',
>   '/com/stackoverflow/questions/ask/',
>   '/uk/co/stackoverflow/questions/ask/', '/uk/co/stackoverflow/',
>   '/uk/co/stackoverflow/']

#### Method 3

If there'd have been one or more subdomains, such as:

```
http://www.subdomain1.subdomain2.stackoverflow.co.uk
http://www.subdomain1.subdomain2.subdomain3.stackoverflow.co.uk
```

Then, we'd simply add a `\.?([a-z0-9]+)?` for each subdomain to our expression:

```
(?im)^(?:https?:\/\/)(?:w{3}\.)?([^\r\n]+?)\.([a-z0-9]+)\.?([a-z0-9]+)?\.?([a-z0-9]+)?\.?([a-z0-9]+)?\.?([a-z0-9]+)?\/?(.*)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/j4p1r6/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion it is very hopeful for me but the problem that your solution not cover large scale of web sites example in http://www.stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/ask must be uk/co/stackoverflow/questions/ask

Comment: what i want that the elements between  / stackoverflow.co.uk/  will be like this uk/co/stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you very much that what i need exactly